# Script to Add Computer Accounts to AD from list

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, automation

Ok, I have tried to google this and keep running into things that are close, but not quite there.  I mess with them for a few hours and can't bridge it across to what I need.

Requirements: Read a list of computer names and add them to specific OUs.

The list can be formated however, but right now I have it as a csv.

/////////

Comp1,Computers,cold,Alaska,mydomain,com,

Comp2,servers,New Jersey,test,temp,training,Room3,trainers,mydomain,com,

Comp3,computers,New Jersey,test,temp,training,Room3,students,restricted,mydomain,com

Comp4,computers,New Jersey,test,temp,training,Room3,students,power users,mydomain,com

////////

As you can see, the domains portion is not the same on all the machines.

I tried using a vbscript but all I would get is "unable to connect to LDap" so I was thinking about storing the lines in an array and using dsadd and building the command line from the variables in the array.

I already have the portion written to browse for the file, and dsquery, dsadd, etc are all on the server that this will be run from.

This is probably a lot easier than I am trying to make it, I tend to over complicate things if I don't finish it right away.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
[Automating the creation of computer accounts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315273)